# Vuejs register component issue in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I registered **App.vue** as the main component in Vue.js but when I use it in Laravel blade I get this console error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

this is my code in **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import routes from './routes'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: history
});

Vue.config.devtools = true;

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

and my **blade**

```
<div id="app">
    <App></App>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

this is the code I write in **App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="app">

        <h1 class="display-4">Hello World from App.vue</h1>

        <router-view />

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Change `<App></App>` for `<router-view />`

Comment: I added `<router-view>` in  App.vue @AdamOrlov

Comment: Remove the `<app></app>` from your blade file. You don't need to add this as you've  already specified that you want to `render` it in your `Vue` instance.

Comment: Logically it should be as you say, but it doesn't show the content of routes and App.js @Rwd

Comment: Is it still showing an error? If not, please can you show the code for your `App` component.

Comment: No, I edit my question and add `App` component @Rwd

Comment: @LoviisaLampinen delete `<App></App>` from your "blade" div. Leave only this part --> `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: I did this, but it does not work, get no error and App.vue does not load @AdamOrlov

Comment: @LoviisaLampinen do you restard your  node server after making changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './views/App'
import Hello from './views/Hello'
import Home from './views/Home'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/hello',
            name: 'hello',
            component: Hello,
        },
    ],
});
```

then in your blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue SPA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <app></app>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also make sure to add this route

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register components like this:

```
Vue.component("Name", require("./components/Name.vue").default);
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js:

```
    require('./bootstrap');
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import routes from './routes'
    import App from './App'

    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(Vuex);

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes,
        mode: history
    });

    Vue.config.devtools = true;

    //import components
    Vue.component(
    'app',
    require('./components/App.vue').default);
    new Vue({
        router,
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app');
```